# aJax REST API call - Curl Works while aJax fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, curl

I'm using a cURL api call and I've converted it to ajax but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --user user:pass https://i.am.web/123456789/events -d "{\"name\": \"Marcus0.1\",\"start\": 500000,\"end\": 1361640526000}"
```

.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://i.am.web/123456789/events',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    data: {
        "name": "Marcus0.3",
        "start": 500000,
        "end": 1361640526000
    },
    success: function(){alert('DONE!');},
    error:function(error){alert(error)},
});
alert("ENDING API MAIN FUNCTION")
```

Chrome errors:

http://i.am.website/123456789  &  POST & 401 unauthorized & text/html  & query.min/js:2 Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cross-domain ajax calls are not permitted. Solution change dataType to jsonp and use GET method, but in your case it's probably impossible.

Comment: Ok, how should I do a cross-domain call? I don't need it to be ajax, but client side would be ideal

Comment: With external api (you cannot changed) the simplest way is to make ajax call to your server and on server make  cURL call. It  is a bit dirty but will works.