# Send ajax request is not working

Tags: ajax, mongodb, jquery, curl

I send following curl request to get result from mongodb.

```
curl --data 'cmd={"geoNear" : "items", "near":[6.8590845,79.9800719]}' 'http://82.196.xxx.xxx:27080/weather/_cmd'
```

It is working. I try to send ajax request to do above curl request.

```
         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://82.196.xxx.xxx:27080/weather/_cmd',
            type: 'POST',
            // dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
            data: {"geoNear" : "items", "near":[6.8590845,79.9800719]},
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
```

I think issue is my data object. curl request has `'cmd={"geoNear" : "items", "near":[6.8590845,79.9800719]}`. But i don't know how it convert to ajax request.

But it is not working. I got `200 OK` status. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069919/ajax-rest-api-call-curl-works-while-ajax-fails?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: It is not my problem. I got 200 status. But i didn't get success message.

Comment: try `data: {cmd: JSON.stringify({"geoNear" : "items", "near":[6.8590845,79.9800719]})}`

Comment: looks like the server is expecting an parameter called `cmd` which a json string as the value

Comment: also change the `fail` logging to `console.log("error", arguments);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny tnx for replay. i tried it. But not work. :(

Comment: give me your url clearly we guide you

Comment: @NathanSrivi - "http://82.196.11.207:27080/weather/_cmd"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/weather/_cmd',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain : true,
    data: {
        cmd: JSON.stringify({
            "geoNear" : "items",
            "near": [6.8590845,79.9800719]
        })
    },
    success: function(res) {
        //do stuff with res
    }
});

ProxyPass /weather http://82.196.11.207:27080/weather/_cmd
ProxyPassReverse /weather http://82.196.11.207:27080/weather/_cmd
```

Add above Proxy pass to your Apache and try this. it will work. problem is you cant pass POST Request by using jsonp. mongo we need POST requests. this is one way to do it. :D i tested it and works perfectly for me.

-update - it will not accept json and you have to pass it as string.